# Can I navigate in Angular SPA to arbitrary html without creating component?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I need to add static content like privacy policy to my aspnet core angular SPA. Obviously the content should be shown as part of SPA and not static html href kinda page.

Is there a way to do so without creating an angular component for each static page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and I did the following:

A simple component with this template:

```
<iframe class="iframe" [src]="url | safe: 'resourceUrl'" [height]="height" [width]="width"></iframe>
```

And I used it from a parent component e.g. like this:

```
<iframe-panel url="assets/doc/index.html"></iframe-panel>
```

Using this mechanism I can show any URL that I wish in this component. I had internal pages as well as external such as privacy policy etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you have 2 options:

1. create a static html file, but it would be out of your angular app. You you would not be able to use the Angular Router to reach it (you would have to use classic `href`). That means once you are on your static page, you can't go back to your angular app without reloading it from scratch (and so, you lose its state).
2. create a component with empty CSS and TypeScript files (expect class declaration and annotations ofc), just HTML.